# USB Drive Write protection and unable to format

Tags: usb-flash-drive, format, write-protect

So I wanted to install Windows 8.1 on my USB but I saw that I need to format it so I tried to format it but it says unable to format or something like that (Btw its Kingston's DT101 G2) I checked on internet and i tried every one they gave and none of it worked so I said ok im gonna try with my older smaller USB (I'm not sure what brand it is , it's some random USB) but that one for some reason has Write Protection on it and then I tried to look up on the Internet i tried one in regedit and one in cmd . What i found is that when in cmd i type ATTRIBUTES DISK it says : ReadOnly State-yes , ReadOnly-no . I think that it's write protected beacuse of That readonly state . I wanted to know if anyone could help with any of these USB Drives

Comment: Flash drives do this when they start to fail.  It's a feature that allows you to get your contents off before it fails completely.

Answer (score 0):

Open a command prompt in elevated mode, and then run DISKPART.  Then run these commands.

DISKPART> list disk

DISKPART> select disk (id)  - make sure you choose the correct one

DISKPART> attributes disk clear readonly

Comment: I already tried this and it set Readonly to no , but readonly state is set to yes . And it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Some USB sticks have a mechanical lock against writing, a small switch on the stick. Make sure it's not set to lock.

Comment: I checked . There's none on it

Answer (score 0):

I had a USB drive that did this, while I tried to install Windows 7. Take my advice with a grain of salt since I'm new here but I just binned mine because I tried everything. Even the diskpart command and it didn't work.